# Tags HTML para Razor Engine (asp.net mvc C#)

Tags: html5, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Estou com dificuldade em minha aplicação web com asp.net mvc, de como criar formulários utilizando a **Razor** Engine.

Abaixo segue meu código HTML.

```
<form class="o-form" method="post">
   <input name="senderName" id="senderName" required="required" type="text" placeholder="Nome*">
   <input type="email" name="senderEmail" id="senderEmail" required="required" placeholder="Email*">
   <input type="text" placeholder="website">
   <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
   <button type="submit" class="btn-small btn-center">Send</button>
</form>
```

Para utilizar a Razor Engine, tentei o seguinte:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome)
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
     @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Mensagem)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mensagem)
     <button type="submit" class="btn-small btn-center">Send</button>
 }
```

E nisso estou enfrentando dificuldades com as tags: `class`, `placeholer`, `required`, e diversas tags **HTML5**, como `data-alguma-coisa`.

Qual a maneira correta de incluir essas tags em meus inputs, utilizando Razor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que o nome e id sejam sobrescritos você devera utilizar TextBoxForem vez de EditFor.
Olhe o exemplo abaixo (incluí o atributo class também):

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nome, new { @class = "classe", Name = "senderName", Id="senderName", Placeholder="Insira seu nome" })

faça o mesmo com os outros campos.
Quanto ao form já vai como method post mesmo. não precisa fazer nada. Só crie outra action com mesmo nome da que exibe o form só que com o atributo [HttpPost] e um model como parâmetro para receber o form.
Qualquer dúvida comente ai que tento responder.
Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado, estava apanhando legal e agora deu tudo certo. Valeu pela ajuda.